# Im Getting The Error Cannot read property 'user' of undefined While Using Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to make an @someone command that ghost pings a random person (annoying, I know) and recently the command has started breaking but only most of the time. About 1 in every 5 times it works and I dont Know what's causing it
Here's the code

```
                } else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}someone`) {
                 message.delete({
                     timeout: 1
                 })
                 const userList = message.guild.members.cache.array();
                 var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * message.guild.memberCount)
                 var pingPerson = userList[randomNumber]
                 message.channel.send("<@" + pingPerson.user.id + ">")
                     .then(msg => {
                         msg.delete({
                             timeout: 1
                         })
                     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check if your `pingPerson` value returns undefined?

In your example you're getting a random number from `message.guild.memberCount` using Math.round which could get you an index which is 1 more than the array length.

Also `message.guild.members.cache.array()` could be different from `message.build.memberCount` which could also be causing your problem.

```
const userList = message.guild.members.cache.array();
var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * message.guild.memberCount)
var pingPerson = userList[randomNumber]
```

Edits

```
const userList = message.guild.members.cache.array();
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * userList.length)
var pingPerson = userList[randomNumber]
```